# Insert a row to SQL table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameters, insert

I am writing a store procedure in T-SQL which inserts a row to the table, based on parameters

```
@UserName ,@CompanyName ,@RestName,@Desc

INSERT INTO Orders(UserId,CompanyId,RestId)
    SELECT UserNames.Id,CompanyNames.Id,RestNames.Id FROM UserNames,CompanyNames,RestNames
    WHERE
    UserNames.Name = @UserName AND 
    CompanyNames.Name = @CompanyName AND
    RestNames.Name = @RestName
```

Besides the insert to the 3 columns above,I also want to insert the `@Desc` value.
I tried :

```
INSERT INTO Orders(UserId,CompanyId,RestId,Desc)
        VALUES(
        (SELECT UserNames.Id,CompanyNames.Id,RestNames.Id FROM UserNames,CompanyNames,RestNames
        WHERE
        UserNames.Name = @UserName AND 
        CompanyNames.Name = @CompanyName AND
        RestNames.Name = @RestName),@Desc)
```

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTSt-
It doesn`t work giving the following error:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@UserName ,@CompanyName ,@RestName,@Desc

INSERT INTO Orders(UserId,CompanyId,RestId, Desc_Column)
SELECT UserNames.Id,CompanyNames.Id,RestNames.Id , @Desc  --<-- Just SELECT that variable
FROM UserNames,CompanyNames,RestNames                        -- in your select statement.
WHERE UserNames.Name = @UserName 
AND CompanyNames.Name = @CompanyName 
AND RestNames.Name = @RestName
```

**Retrieve ID Values Inserted**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT);   --<-- Declare a table variable 

INSERT INTO Orders(UserId,CompanyId,RestId, Desc_Column)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID    INTO @t                        --<-- use OUTPUT, get values from INSERTED Table
SELECT UserNames.Id,CompanyNames.Id,RestNames.Id , @Desc  --and insert them into your table variable
FROM UserNames,CompanyNames,RestNames                        
WHERE UserNames.Name = @UserName 
AND CompanyNames.Name = @CompanyName 
AND RestNames.Name = @RestName

/*At last just simply select from that table variable to get the inserted IDs*/
 SELECT * FROM @t
```

Comment: Otherwise, use `[Desc]` if that is the column name, as it's a SQL keyword.

Comment: @M.Ali - Thank you - it works!How can this query also return a value of a new (inserted ) row?ID

Comment: @Yakov do you mean the ID generated by the Identity column ?? or the ID you have just inserted ???

Comment: @M.Ali - yes!the ID generated by the Identity column

Comment: @M.Ali - I need to return only the ID,of the inserted row

Comment: It will return any Inserted ID or IDs, it should work for both single or multiple values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44290/discussion-between-yakov-and-m-ali)